# HTTP request as Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I am a newbie to angular 2 and Observable.
I have a function `getCurrentUserDetails()` as service, which returns an observable with the details of current user. I am using this on every route access.

I want to limit my http request to database each time i access this function.

I want to create a function which returns the data if available else create a http request get the data and return that data.

Below is the code which i tried:

```
private currentUser: any;
getCurrentUserDetails(){

        if(!this.currentUser){
            this.currentUser = this._http.get('getcurrentuserdetails').map((res:Response) => res.json()).share();
            return this.currentUser;
        }
        else {
            return this.currentUser;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like this instead of the `share()` operator:

```
publishReplay()->refCount()->take(1)
```

This means that every time you subscribe to this Observable you'll receive the cached value and the `take(1)` operator will make the chain complete immediately without subscribing to the source and causing more HTTP requests.